# Problem with minikube and nginx ingress when reinstalled minikube

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, minikube, nginx-ingress, skaffold

When I'm running following code:

```sh
minikube addons enable ingress
```

I'm getting following error:

```sh
▪ Using image k8s.gcr.io/ingress-nginx/controller:v0.44.0
    ▪ Using image docker.io/jettech/kube-webhook-certgen:v1.5.1
    ▪ Using image docker.io/jettech/kube-webhook-certgen:v1.5.1
  Verifying ingress addon...

❌  Exiting due to MK_ENABLE: run callbacks: running callbacks: [sudo KUBECONFIG=/var/lib/minikube/kubeconfig /var/lib/minikube/binaries/v1.20.2/kubectl apply -f /etc/kubernetes/addons/ingress-configmap.yaml -f /etc/kubernetes/addons/ingress-rbac.yaml -f /etc/kubernetes/addons/ingress-dp.yaml: Process exited with status 1
stdout:
namespace/ingress-nginx unchanged
configmap/ingress-nginx-controller unchanged
configmap/tcp-services unchanged
configmap/udp-services unchanged
serviceaccount/ingress-nginx unchanged
clusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/ingress-nginx unchanged
clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/ingress-nginx unchanged
role.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/ingress-nginx unchanged
rolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/ingress-nginx unchanged
serviceaccount/ingress-nginx-admission unchanged
clusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/ingress-nginx-admission unchanged
clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/ingress-nginx-admission unchanged
role.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/ingress-nginx-admission unchanged
rolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/ingress-nginx-admission unchanged
service/ingress-nginx-controller-admission unchanged
service/ingress-nginx-controller unchanged
validatingwebhookconfiguration.admissionregistration.k8s.io/ingress-nginx-admission configured

stderr:
Error from server (Invalid): error when applying patch:
{"metadata":{"annotations":{"kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration":"{\"apiVersion\":\"apps/v1\",\"kind\":\"Deployment\",\"metadata\":{\"annotations\":{},\"labels\":{\"addonmanager.kubernetes.io/mode\":\"Reconcile\",\"app.kubernetes.io/component\":\"controller\",\"app.kubernetes.io/instance\":\"ingress-nginx\",\"app.kubernetes.io/name\":\"ingress-nginx\"},\"name\":\"ingress-nginx-controller\",\"namespace\":\"ingress-nginx\"},\"spec\":{\"minReadySeconds\":0,\"revisionHistoryLimit\":10,\"selector\":{\"matchLabels\":{\"addonmanager.kubernetes.io/mode\":\"Reconcile\",\"app.kubernetes.io/component\":\"controller\",\"app.kubernetes.io/instance\":\"ingress-nginx\",\"app.kubernetes.io/name\":\"ingress-nginx\"}},\"strategy\":{\"rollingUpdate\":{\"maxUnavailable\":1},\"type\":\"RollingUpdate\"},\"template\":{\"metadata\":{\"labels\":{\"addonmanager.kubernetes.io/mode\":\"Reconcile\",\"app.kubernetes.io/component\":\"controller\",\"app.kubernetes.io/instance\":\"ingress-nginx\",\"app.kubernetes.io/name\":\"ingress-nginx\",\"gcp-auth-skip-secret\":\"true\"}},\"spec\":{\"containers\":[{\"args\":[\"/nginx-ingress-controller\",\"--ingress-class=nginx\",\"--configmap=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/ingress-nginx-controller\",\"--report-node-internal-ip-address\",\"--tcp-services-configmap=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/tcp-services\",\"--udp-services-configmap=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/udp-services\",\"--validating-webhook=:8443\",\"--validating-webhook-certificate=/usr/local/certificates/cert\",\"--validating-webhook-key=/usr/local/certificates/key\"],\"env\":[{\"name\":\"POD_NAME\",\"valueFrom\":{\"fieldRef\":{\"fieldPath\":\"metadata.name\"}}},{\"name\":\"POD_NAMESPACE\",\"valueFrom\":{\"fieldRef\":{\"fieldPath\":\"metadata.namespace\"}}},{\"name\":\"LD_PRELOAD\",\"value\":\"/usr/local/lib/libmimalloc.so\"}],\"image\":\"k8s.gcr.io/ingress-nginx/controller:v0.44.0@sha256:3dd0fac48073beaca2d67a78c746c7593f9c575168a17139a9955a82c63c4b9a\",\"imagePullPolicy\":\"IfNotPresent\",\"lifecycle\":{\"preStop\":{\"exec\":{\"command\":[\"/wait-shutdown\"]}}},\"livenessProbe\":{\"failureThreshold\":5,\"httpGet\":{\"path\":\"/healthz\",\"port\":10254,\"scheme\":\"HTTP\"},\"initialDelaySeconds\":10,\"periodSeconds\":10,\"successThreshold\":1,\"timeoutSeconds\":1},\"name\":\"controller\",\"ports\":[{\"containerPort\":80,\"hostPort\":80,\"name\":\"http\",\"protocol\":\"TCP\"},{\"containerPort\":443,\"hostPort\":443,\"name\":\"https\",\"protocol\":\"TCP\"},{\"containerPort\":8443,\"name\":\"webhook\",\"protocol\":\"TCP\"}],\"readinessProbe\":{\"failureThreshold\":3,\"httpGet\":{\"path\":\"/healthz\",\"port\":10254,\"scheme\":\"HTTP\"},\"initialDelaySeconds\":10,\"periodSeconds\":10,\"successThreshold\":1,\"timeoutSeconds\":1},\"resources\":{\"requests\":{\"cpu\":\"100m\",\"memory\":\"90Mi\"}},\"securityContext\":{\"allowPrivilegeEscalation\":true,\"capabilities\":{\"add\":[\"NET_BIND_SERVICE\"],\"drop\":[\"ALL\"]},\"runAsUser\":101},\"volumeMounts\":[{\"mountPath\":\"/usr/local/certificates/\",\"name\":\"webhook-cert\",\"readOnly\":true}]}],\"dnsPolicy\":\"ClusterFirst\",\"serviceAccountName\":\"ingress-nginx\",\"volumes\":[{\"name\":\"webhook-cert\",\"secret\":{\"secretName\":\"ingress-nginx-admission\"}}]}}}}\n"},"labels":{"addonmanager.kubernetes.io/mode":"Reconcile","app.kubernetes.io/managed-by":null,"app.kubernetes.io/version":null,"helm.sh/chart":null}},"spec":{"minReadySeconds":0,"selector":{"matchLabels":{"addonmanager.kubernetes.io/mode":"Reconcile"}},"strategy":{"$retainKeys":["rollingUpdate","type"],"rollingUpdate":{"maxUnavailable":1}},"template":{"metadata":{"labels":{"addonmanager.kubernetes.io/mode":"Reconcile","gcp-auth-skip-secret":"true"}},"spec":{"$setElementOrder/containers":[{"name":"controller"}],"containers":[{"$setElementOrder/ports":[{"containerPort":80},{"containerPort":443},{"containerPort":8443}],"args":["/nginx-ingress-controller","--ingress-class=nginx","--configmap=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/ingress-nginx-controller","--report-node-internal-ip-address","--tcp-services-configmap=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/tcp-services","--udp-services-configmap=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/udp-services","--validating-webhook=:8443","--validating-webhook-certificate=/usr/local/certificates/cert","--validating-webhook-key=/usr/local/certificates/key"],"image":"k8s.gcr.io/ingress-nginx/controller:v0.44.0@sha256:3dd0fac48073beaca2d67a78c746c7593f9c575168a17139a9955a82c63c4b9a","name":"controller","ports":[{"containerPort":80,"hostPort":80},{"containerPort":443,"hostPort":443}]}],"nodeSelector":null,"terminationGracePeriodSeconds":null}}}}
to:
Resource: "apps/v1, Resource=deployments", GroupVersionKind: "apps/v1, Kind=Deployment"
Name: "ingress-nginx-controller", Namespace: "ingress-nginx"
for: "/etc/kubernetes/addons/ingress-dp.yaml": Deployment.apps "ingress-nginx-controller" is invalid: spec.selector: Invalid value: v1.LabelSelector{MatchLabels:map[string]string{"addonmanager.kubernetes.io/mode":"Reconcile", "app.kubernetes.io/component":"controller", "app.kubernetes.io/instance":"ingress-nginx", "app.kubernetes.io/name":"ingress-nginx"}, MatchExpressions:[]v1.LabelSelectorRequirement(nil)}: field is immutable
Error from server (Invalid): error when applying patch:
{"metadata":{"annotations":{"helm.sh/hook":null,"helm.sh/hook-delete-policy":null,"kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration":"{\"apiVersion\":\"batch/v1\",\"kind\":\"Job\",\"metadata\":{\"annotations\":{},\"labels\":{\"addonmanager.kubernetes.io/mode\":\"Reconcile\",\"app.kubernetes.io/component\":\"admission-webhook\",\"app.kubernetes.io/instance\":\"ingress-nginx\",\"app.kubernetes.io/name\":\"ingress-nginx\"},\"name\":\"ingress-nginx-admission-create\",\"namespace\":\"ingress-nginx\"},\"spec\":{\"template\":{\"metadata\":{\"labels\":{\"addonmanager.kubernetes.io/mode\":\"Reconcile\",\"app.kubernetes.io/component\":\"admission-webhook\",\"app.kubernetes.io/instance\":\"ingress-nginx\",\"app.kubernetes.io/name\":\"ingress-nginx\"},\"name\":\"ingress-nginx-admission-create\"},\"spec\":{\"containers\":[{\"args\":[\"create\",\"--host=ingress-nginx-controller-admission,ingress-nginx-controller-admission.$(POD_NAMESPACE).svc\",\"--namespace=$(POD_NAMESPACE)\",\"--secret-name=ingress-nginx-admission\"],\"env\":[{\"name\":\"POD_NAMESPACE\",\"valueFrom\":{\"fieldRef\":{\"fieldPath\":\"metadata.namespace\"}}}],\"image\":\"docker.io/jettech/kube-webhook-certgen:v1.5.1@sha256:950833e19ade18cd389d647efb88992a7cc077abedef343fa59e012d376d79b7\",\"imagePullPolicy\":\"IfNotPresent\",\"name\":\"create\"}],\"restartPolicy\":\"OnFailure\",\"securityContext\":{\"runAsNonRoot\":true,\"runAsUser\":2000},\"serviceAccountName\":\"ingress-nginx-admission\"}}}}\n"},"labels":{"addonmanager.kubernetes.io/mode":"Reconcile","app.kubernetes.io/managed-by":null,"app.kubernetes.io/version":null,"helm.sh/chart":null}},"spec":{"template":{"metadata":{"labels":{"addonmanager.kubernetes.io/mode":"Reconcile","app.kubernetes.io/managed-by":null,"app.kubernetes.io/version":null,"helm.sh/chart":null}},"spec":{"$setElementOrder/containers":[{"name":"create"}],"containers":[{"image":"docker.io/jettech/kube-webhook-certgen:v1.5.1@sha256:950833e19ade18cd389d647efb88992a7cc077abedef343fa59e012d376d79b7","name":"create"}]}}}}
to:
Resource: "batch/v1, Resource=jobs", GroupVersionKind: "batch/v1, Kind=Job"
Name: "ingress-nginx-admission-create", Namespace: "ingress-nginx"
for: "/etc/kubernetes/addons/ingress-dp.yaml": Job.batch "ingress-nginx-admission-create" is invalid: spec.template: Invalid value: core.PodTemplateSpec{ObjectMeta:v1.ObjectMeta{Name:"ingress-nginx-admission-create", GenerateName:"", Namespace:"", SelfLink:"", UID:"", ResourceVersion:"", Generation:0, CreationTimestamp:v1.Time{Time:time.Time{wall:0x0, ext:0, loc:(*time.Location)(nil)}}, DeletionTimestamp:(*v1.Time)(nil), DeletionGracePeriodSeconds:(*int64)(nil), Labels:map[string]string{"addonmanager.kubernetes.io/mode":"Reconcile", "app.kubernetes.io/component":"admission-webhook", "app.kubernetes.io/instance":"ingress-nginx", "app.kubernetes.io/name":"ingress-nginx", "controller-uid":"d33a74a3-101c-4e82-a2b7-45b46068f189", "job-name":"ingress-nginx-admission-create"}, Annotations:map[string]string(nil), OwnerReferences:[]v1.OwnerReference(nil), Finalizers:[]string(nil), ClusterName:"", ManagedFields:[]v1.ManagedFieldsEntry(nil)}, Spec:core.PodSpec{Volumes:[]core.Volume(nil), InitContainers:[]core.Container(nil), Containers:[]core.Container{core.Container{Name:"create", Image:"docker.io/jettech/kube-webhook-certgen:v1.5.1@sha256:950833e19ade18cd389d647efb88992a7cc077abedef343fa59e012d376d79b7", Command:[]string(nil), Args:[]string{"create", "--host=ingress-nginx-controller-admission,ingress-nginx-controller-admission.$(POD_NAMESPACE).svc", "--namespace=$(POD_NAMESPACE)", "--secret-name=ingress-nginx-admission"}, WorkingDir:"", Ports:[]core.ContainerPort(nil), EnvFrom:[]core.EnvFromSource(nil), Env:[]core.EnvVar{core.EnvVar{Name:"POD_NAMESPACE", Value:"", ValueFrom:(*core.EnvVarSource)(0xc00a79dea0)}}, Resources:core.ResourceRequirements{Limits:core.ResourceList(nil), Requests:core.ResourceList(nil)}, VolumeMounts:[]core.VolumeMount(nil), VolumeDevices:[]core.VolumeDevice(nil), LivenessProbe:(*core.Probe)(nil), ReadinessProbe:(*core.Probe)(nil), StartupProbe:(*core.Probe)(nil), Lifecycle:(*core.Lifecycle)(nil), TerminationMessagePath:"/dev/termination-log", TerminationMessagePolicy:"File", ImagePullPolicy:"IfNotPresent", SecurityContext:(*core.SecurityContext)(nil), Stdin:false, StdinOnce:false, TTY:false}}, EphemeralContainers:[]core.EphemeralContainer(nil), RestartPolicy:"OnFailure", TerminationGracePeriodSeconds:(*int64)(0xc003184dc0), ActiveDeadlineSeconds:(*int64)(nil), DNSPolicy:"ClusterFirst", NodeSelector:map[string]string(nil), ServiceAccountName:"ingress-nginx-admission", AutomountServiceAccountToken:(*bool)(nil), NodeName:"", SecurityContext:(*core.PodSecurityContext)(0xc010b3d980), ImagePullSecrets:[]core.LocalObjectReference(nil), Hostname:"", Subdomain:"", SetHostnameAsFQDN:(*bool)(nil), Affinity:(*core.Affinity)(nil), SchedulerName:"default-scheduler", Tolerations:[]core.Toleration(nil), HostAliases:[]core.HostAlias(nil), PriorityClassName:"", Priority:(*int32)(nil), PreemptionPolicy:(*core.PreemptionPolicy)(nil), DNSConfig:(*core.PodDNSConfig)(nil), ReadinessGates:[]core.PodReadinessGate(nil), RuntimeClassName:(*string)(nil), Overhead:core.ResourceList(nil), EnableServiceLinks:(*bool)(nil), TopologySpreadConstraints:[]core.TopologySpreadConstraint(nil)}}: field is immutable
Error from server (Invalid): error when applying patch:
{"metadata":{"annotations":{"helm.sh/hook":null,"helm.sh/hook-delete-policy":null,"kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration":"{\"apiVersion\":\"batch/v1\",\"kind\":\"Job\",\"metadata\":{\"annotations\":{},\"labels\":{\"addonmanager.kubernetes.io/mode\":\"Reconcile\",\"app.kubernetes.io/component\":\"admission-webhook\",\"app.kubernetes.io/instance\":\"ingress-nginx\",\"app.kubernetes.io/name\":\"ingress-nginx\"},\"name\":\"ingress-nginx-admission-patch\",\"namespace\":\"ingress-nginx\"},\"spec\":{\"template\":{\"metadata\":{\"labels\":{\"addonmanager.kubernetes.io/mode\":\"Reconcile\",\"app.kubernetes.io/component\":\"admission-webhook\",\"app.kubernetes.io/instance\":\"ingress-nginx\",\"app.kubernetes.io/name\":\"ingress-nginx\"},\"name\":\"ingress-nginx-admission-patch\"},\"spec\":{\"containers\":[{\"args\":[\"patch\",\"--webhook-name=ingress-nginx-admission\",\"--namespace=$(POD_NAMESPACE)\",\"--patch-mutating=false\",\"--secret-name=ingress-nginx-admission\",\"--patch-failure-policy=Fail\"],\"env\":[{\"name\":\"POD_NAMESPACE\",\"valueFrom\":{\"fieldRef\":{\"fieldPath\":\"metadata.namespace\"}}}],\"image\":\"docker.io/jettech/kube-webhook-certgen:v1.5.1@sha256:950833e19ade18cd389d647efb88992a7cc077abedef343fa59e012d376d79b7\",\"imagePullPolicy\":\"IfNotPresent\",\"name\":\"patch\"}],\"restartPolicy\":\"OnFailure\",\"securityContext\":{\"runAsNonRoot\":true,\"runAsUser\":2000},\"serviceAccountName\":\"ingress-nginx-admission\"}}}}\n"},"labels":{"addonmanager.kubernetes.io/mode":"Reconcile","app.kubernetes.io/managed-by":null,"app.kubernetes.io/version":null,"helm.sh/chart":null}},"spec":{"template":{"metadata":{"labels":{"addonmanager.kubernetes.io/mode":"Reconcile","app.kubernetes.io/managed-by":null,"app.kubernetes.io/version":null,"helm.sh/chart":null}},"spec":{"$setElementOrder/containers":[{"name":"patch"}],"containers":[{"image":"docker.io/jettech/kube-webhook-certgen:v1.5.1@sha256:950833e19ade18cd389d647efb88992a7cc077abedef343fa59e012d376d79b7","name":"patch"}]}}}}
to:
Resource: "batch/v1, Resource=jobs", GroupVersionKind: "batch/v1, Kind=Job"
Name: "ingress-nginx-admission-patch", Namespace: "ingress-nginx"
for: "/etc/kubernetes/addons/ingress-dp.yaml": Job.batch "ingress-nginx-admission-patch" is invalid: spec.template: Invalid value: core.PodTemplateSpec{ObjectMeta:v1.ObjectMeta{Name:"ingress-nginx-admission-patch", GenerateName:"", Namespace:"", SelfLink:"", UID:"", ResourceVersion:"", Generation:0, CreationTimestamp:v1.Time{Time:time.Time{wall:0x0, ext:0, loc:(*time.Location)(nil)}}, DeletionTimestamp:(*v1.Time)(nil), DeletionGracePeriodSeconds:(*int64)(nil), Labels:map[string]string{"addonmanager.kubernetes.io/mode":"Reconcile", "app.kubernetes.io/component":"admission-webhook", "app.kubernetes.io/instance":"ingress-nginx", "app.kubernetes.io/name":"ingress-nginx", "controller-uid":"ef303f40-b52d-49c5-ab80-8330379fed36", "job-name":"ingress-nginx-admission-patch"}, Annotations:map[string]string(nil), OwnerReferences:[]v1.OwnerReference(nil), Finalizers:[]string(nil), ClusterName:"", ManagedFields:[]v1.ManagedFieldsEntry(nil)}, Spec:core.PodSpec{Volumes:[]core.Volume(nil), InitContainers:[]core.Container(nil), Containers:[]core.Container{core.Container{Name:"patch", Image:"docker.io/jettech/kube-webhook-certgen:v1.5.1@sha256:950833e19ade18cd389d647efb88992a7cc077abedef343fa59e012d376d79b7", Command:[]string(nil), Args:[]string{"patch", "--webhook-name=ingress-nginx-admission", "--namespace=$(POD_NAMESPACE)", "--patch-mutating=false", "--secret-name=ingress-nginx-admission", "--patch-failure-policy=Fail"}, WorkingDir:"", Ports:[]core.ContainerPort(nil), EnvFrom:[]core.EnvFromSource(nil), Env:[]core.EnvVar{core.EnvVar{Name:"POD_NAMESPACE", Value:"", ValueFrom:(*core.EnvVarSource)(0xc00fd798a0)}}, Resources:core.ResourceRequirements{Limits:core.ResourceList(nil), Requests:core.ResourceList(nil)}, VolumeMounts:[]core.VolumeMount(nil), VolumeDevices:[]core.VolumeDevice(nil), LivenessProbe:(*core.Probe)(nil), ReadinessProbe:(*core.Probe)(nil), StartupProbe:(*core.Probe)(nil), Lifecycle:(*core.Lifecycle)(nil), TerminationMessagePath:"/dev/termination-log", TerminationMessagePolicy:"File", ImagePullPolicy:"IfNotPresent", SecurityContext:(*core.SecurityContext)(nil), Stdin:false, StdinOnce:false, TTY:false}}, EphemeralContainers:[]core.EphemeralContainer(nil), RestartPolicy:"OnFailure", TerminationGracePeriodSeconds:(*int64)(0xc00573d190), ActiveDeadlineSeconds:(*int64)(nil), DNSPolicy:"ClusterFirst", NodeSelector:map[string]string(nil), ServiceAccountName:"ingress-nginx-admission", AutomountServiceAccountToken:(*bool)(nil), NodeName:"", SecurityContext:(*core.PodSecurityContext)(0xc00d7d9100), ImagePullSecrets:[]core.LocalObjectReference(nil), Hostname:"", Subdomain:"", SetHostnameAsFQDN:(*bool)(nil), Affinity:(*core.Affinity)(nil), SchedulerName:"default-scheduler", Tolerations:[]core.Toleration(nil), HostAliases:[]core.HostAlias(nil), PriorityClassName:"", Priority:(*int32)(nil), PreemptionPolicy:(*core.PreemptionPolicy)(nil), DNSConfig:(*core.PodDNSConfig)(nil), ReadinessGates:[]core.PodReadinessGate(nil), RuntimeClassName:(*string)(nil), Overhead:core.ResourceList(nil), EnableServiceLinks:(*bool)(nil), TopologySpreadConstraints:[]core.TopologySpreadConstraint(nil)}}: field is immutable
]

  If the above advice does not help, please let us know: 
  https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/new/choose
```

So I had some bug issue in my PC. So, i reinstall minikube. After this when I use `minikube start` and all want fine. But when i enable ingress then the above error was showing.

And when i run `skaffold dev` the following error was showing:

```sh
Warning: extensions/v1beta1 Ingress is deprecated in v1.14+, unavailable in v1.22+; use networking.k8s.io/v1 Ingress
 - Error from server (InternalError): error when creating "STDIN": Internal error occurred: failed calling webhook "validate.nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io": an error on the server ("") has prevented the request from succeeding
exiting dev mode because first deploy failed: kubectl apply: exit status 1
```

Comment: This sounds like https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/11121.

Comment: Which [minikube driver](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/drivers/) are you using ? 
Which version of minikube do you have ?
Is minikube running on a Linux or Windows machine ?

Comment: It's on ubuntu 20.04, minikube version: v1.19.0, and im using minikube with docker and kubernetes and also skaffold, `eval $(minikube docker-env)`. I'm just a beginner in this.

Comment: It's odd that your output is showing `unchanged` for many of the resources being installed.  There is a similar question where the user discovered they had a left over validation webhook; deleting that restored their setup https://stackoverflow.com/a/67213633/600339.  Otherwise it may be worth a  `minikube delete` and starting anew.

Comment: thank you so much @BriandeAlwis, this help me a lot and also work but i have to run this each time is turn on minikube using `minikube start`. Is there way to permanent fix this??

Comment: I work with some of the Minikube maintainers and will ask.

Comment: This is being tracked at https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/11121

Comment: Okay, thank you so much for your help :) , updated me if you get something, and Answer this question and i will accept it.

Comment: Fix should be in this week's beta (normally Fridays), and the stable release early next week.

Comment: @Ishan Joshi Is it possible for you to check if this [v1.20.0-beta.0](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/releases/tag/v1.20.0-beta.0) release fixes the problem ?

Comment: @matt_j I reinstalled the whole Ubuntu OS in SSD and minikube is working fine then also i can check but I'm doing internship, is this risky?? If it doen't work then there can be a problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As **@Brian de Alwis** pointed out in the comments section, this PR [#11189](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/pull/11189) should resolve the above issue.

You can try the [v1.20.0-beta.0](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/releases/tag/v1.20.0-beta.0) release with this fix. Additionally, a stable [v1.20.0](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/releases/tag/v1.20.0) version is now available.

Comment: did'nt fix minikube version: v1.20.0 - same `Exiting due to MK_ENABLE`

Comment: Worked for me with v1.21.0

Answer (score 0):

The following commands solve the issue on macOs:

```
minikube delete --all
minikube start --vm=true
minikube addons enable ingress
```

Answer (score 0):

1.minikube delete --all

2.minikube start --cpus 2 --memory 4096

- try to increase resources for the minikube.

3. minikube addons enable ingress